# Can anyone explain how to shutdown the Linux system using system command?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system

I stuck in a problem, I want to shutdown the Linux PC using system command but my machine is asking to enter the password.

here is the scenario: I'm using 2 systems one is windows and another one is Linux. I'll send the command to Linux for shutdown, this Linux PC application made it as Service file, once I receive the command for shutdown, My Linux PC run the system function which is written like this ***system("shutdown -P now");*** if I run this command my machine won't execute the command.

Kindly help me out in this!
Thanks & Regards

Comment: The `shutdown` command requires super-user privileges, there's no way around that. What you can do is use some command to elevate your privileges, which often requires you to write your password.

Answer (score 0):

thank you [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) for your valuable feedback. Posting your suggestion as answer to help other community members.

> The `shutdown` command needs super-user privileges.  You can use some
> additional commands to elevate the privileges along with the command
> you are currently using.